# como puedo hacer para que mi usar la tecla windows+M

Tags: c#

buenas estoy trabajos en el lenguaje c# pero quisiera que mi aplicación se pueda minimizar con la tecla windows+M muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: es wpf? windows forms? que has intentado? completa tu pregunta sino es imposible ayudarte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No debes hacer nada. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> actúa por _encima_ de tu aplicación, a nivel del _shell_ de Windows y la va a minimizar, a menos que hayas hecho algo para que no se minimice.

Answer (score -1):

Tiene que configurar windows keyPrewiew = true luego puedes hacer esto:(obviamente en windows form)
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void inicio_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.M  )
            MessageBox.Show("My message");
        //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

si necesitas específicamente la tecla windows puedes ver este esta [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244063/how-to-get-a-combination-of-keys-in-c-sharp)

Un saludo